# Restore original definition of $

Tags: math-mode, tables, incompatibility

I found an incompatibility between `onlyamsmath` and `tabu`, related to the redefinition of the `$`-sign. (Its is an active char, and thus breaks inside tabu columns specifiers). This is triggered with:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[all,error]{onlyamsmath}
\usepackage{tabu}
\begin{document}
\begin{tabu} to 0.6\textwidth{X[c]X[c]X[$c]} 
a & b & c\\ 
\end{tabu} 
\end{document}
```

If I could restore the original definition of `$` at the beginning of the document I could work around the bug. Note that I want to include this 'bugfix' in a package and can not rely on the correct loading order. So I do not want to enforce loading before `onlyamsmath`.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can patch the `tabu` environment so that it sets the correct catcode

```
\usepackage{tabu}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\AtBeginEnvironment{tabu}{\catcode`$=3 }
```

In this way the "protection" given by **onlyamsmath** is disabled only inside the `tabu` environment.

Answer (score 4):

You need to set the catcode of `$` back to its normal value of 3. However, `onlyamsmath` does this at-begin-document and you need to change it back *after* that. In order to ensure that, you can use the `filehook` package and then:

```
\AtEndOfPackageFile*{onlyamsmath}{\AtBeginDocument{\catcode`\$=3\relax}}
```

Which will install the required code in the at-begin-document hook at the end of `onlyamsmath`, if it gets loaded or immediately, if it was already loaded.

Full example (both orders work):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\usepackage{filehook}
\AtEndOfPackageFile*{onlyamsmath}{\AtBeginDocument{\catcode`\$=3\relax}}

\usepackage[all,error]{onlyamsmath}
\usepackage{tabu}

%\usepackage{filehook}
%\AtEndOfPackageFile*{onlyamsmath}{\AtBeginDocument{\catcode`\$=3\relax}}

\begin{document}
\begin{tabu} to 0.6\textwidth{X[c]X[c]X[$c]} 
a & b & c\\ 
\end{tabu} 
\end{document}
```

Comment: This disables many of the features of **onlyamsmath**.

Comment: @egreg: I guessed so, but I simply delivered as ordered.